# Amount of linearly independent vectors and linear subspaces in a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let K be a finite field with q elements and V an n-dimensional vector space with k $\in$ ℕ and k≥1. For 1≤k≤n I want to show that there are
$$\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (q^n-q^i)$$
k-tupels of linearly independent vectors
and
$$\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (\tfrac{q^{n-1}-1}{q^{k-1}-1})$$
k-dimensional linear subspaces of V.

Comment: Can you state / elaborate on your ideas? It seems like you're on the right track, but will need to know what you're thinking of in your head,

Comment: @CalvinLin I am not entirely sure, I know that the cartesian product results in a tupel. If there are 2 Elements than there are 6 solutions in Dimension 2 with k=2. Because there is (e1,0);(e2,0);(e1,e2);(e2,e1);(0,e1);(0,e2). Maybe one can solve this by induction?

Comment: Think about how many choices you have for the first vector in the basis, and then the second vector in the basis, and so on and so forth.

Comment: @CalvinLin For v_j there are q^n-q^j-1 possibilities... mh

Comment: Right, so by the rule of product, how many k-tuples do we have?

Comment: @CalvinLin L(v1,...,vj) has q^j elements

Comment: @CalvinLin Ok I guess I know the answer, I will answer it myself, thanks for the help and support

Comment: Great, go for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my derivation:

$$(i)$$
Step 1: Showing that a vector space $V$ of dimension n over the finite field
$K$ has $p^n$ elements.

Since $V$ is a vector space of dimension $n$, there is a basis $B = \{\ e_2, ... , e_n \}$ with $n$ elements. Every element $v \in V$ now has a (unique) representation as a linear combination $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \lambda_ie_i$ with coefficients from the
field $K$. For each of the $n$ basis vectors $e_i$ one then has $q$ possibilities
to choose a coefficient. In total one obtains $q^n$ different
elements. $\square$

Step 2: Amount of $k$-tupels in general.

First the number of $k$-tuples of linearly independent vectors: For the first vector one can choose any element $v \neq 0$ from $V$, which means that there are $q^n-1$ possibilities.
The second vector cannot be a multiple of the first: $q^n-q$ possibilities. The third vector must not
lie in the product of the first two: $q^n-q^2$
For
the last vector we receive $q^n-q^{k-1}$ possibilities.

Step 3: Combination of all possibilities.

So there is a total of $$\prod_{i=1}^{k} (q^n-q^{i-1})$$ k-tuples. Now in order to get the given equation we shift the indices.

Notice that
$$\prod_{i=1}^{k} (q^n-q^{i-1})=(q^n-q^{1-1})\cdot(q^n-q^{2-1})\cdot...\cdot(q^n-q^{k-1})=\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (q^n-q^{i})$$
Thus we get the hypothesis. $\square$

$$(ii)$$ The linearly independent systems generate the subspace but since the basis is not unique one has to divide by the number of bases which is $(q^k-1)\cdot(q^k-q)\cdot...\cdot(q^k-q^{k-1})$.

This gives us
$$\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \tfrac{q^n-q^{i}}{q^k-q^{i}}=\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \tfrac{q^n-q^{i}}{q^k-q^{i}}\cdot\tfrac{q^{-i}}{q^{-i}}=\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \tfrac{q^{n-i}-1}{q^{k-1}-1}$$
which is our hypothesis. $\square$